# how to configure hibernate not to update @Version on each access to entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i have a simple query that returns an entity, and when i look at hibernate SQL output i see that when i execute this query hibernate updates the @Version field (on each consecutive read the @version field is updated). i dont modify anything in the entity i fetch, and i dont pass is as an argument to either persist or merge. this effectively means every read i make turns into a read+write.
i've tried setting the lock mode t oboth NONE (jpa 2) and READ (jpa 1) to no avail.

is there any way to achieve this? if so, is there any way to set this as the default behavior in persistence.xml in some way ?

im using jpa2 over hibernate 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a open [Hibernate bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5867) relating to version increments on read operations, which occurs under the following conditions:

1. The entity has a component class or subclasses
2. The component/subclasses must use an custom usertype
3. The read operation is covered by transaction

It is marked critical so will hopefully be resolved in a near future release.

Comment: According to the mentioned bug report, it's not a bug, but an  erroneous custom usertype